# Is it proper convention to just name a GitHub remote `github`?

Tags: git, syntax, convention

I ask because I use Heroku and the remote by default is just named `heroku`.

Makes sense to me, I've just never seen anyone else do this.

Answer (score 2):

> Is it proper syntax to...

This isn't a question of "syntax". You can call your remotes whatever you want, but *convention* is to have a remote called "origin" which is the default setup by Git (not Github) when you clone a repository.

You're welcome to rename "origin" to whatever you'd like, but the reason you've not seen other people doing this is that "origin" is the common convention and there is no compelling reason to rename it.